# pandas frequency table histograms distribution fitting

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have a frequency table `df` with large frequencies like this

```
...         freq
(20, 21]    5235211
(21, 22]    5232121
(22, 23]    1241228
(23, 24]    9412034
(24, 25]    2356336
(25, 26]    3782721
(26, 27]    9978733
...
```

The bins are indices.

I want to plot nice histograms with distribution fitting like [here](https://stanford.edu/~mwaskom/software/seaborn/tutorial/distributions.html). But 
that function (`sns.distplot`) along with other distribution plots (`df.plot.kde`, `df.plot.hist`, `df.plot.density`, etc) only take 1D lists or `Series`.

How can I get the same results by using a frequency table instead? It is unpractical to flatten `df` to a 1D array, due to its large size.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found it, `plt.hist` has a parameter named `weights`, to which I can pass an array of weights. Simply passing the `freq` column to `plt.hist` does the trick. With Seaborn:

```
sns.distplot(df.index, hist_kws={"weights":list(df.freq)})
```